# How to enable touch events for Firefox >= 39 on Windows with a touch screen

Tags: javascript, firefox, touch

There already are some questions on SO how to enable touch events with Firefox on Windows, but all I could find basically boil down to “go to about:config and set dom.w3c_touch_events.enabled to 1 (or 2)”.

But with the current Firefox 46 (it seems to me this behavior started with version 39), dom.w3c_touch_events.enabled seems to be without any effect.

[caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=touch) mentions it can be enabled, [a page on developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events) mentions the same.

What am I missing? How can I enable touch events?

**Details:**

I tried on Windows 8.1 and 10. I’m seeing the expected behavior with IE (no touch, but pointer events), Edge (touch and pointer events after turning them on), and Vivaldi (touch events, didn’t try other Chromium browsers).

Using the test page below, I see the following behavior with Firefox 46:

- No touch events ever.
- Using the touch screen (and finger), click and pointer events only when the finger is moved. (Pointer events of course after setting dom.w3c_pointer_events.enabled to true.) That, among others, makes pressing a button unreliable.
- Zooming via pinching is always possible.
- dom.w3c_pointer_events.enabled and layers.async-pan-zoom.enabled have no effect on touch events.

Other test pages (such as the PEP test pages, https://jquery.github.io/PEP/) show the same behavior. What am I missing?

Test page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
  <style type="text/css" tag="DisallowSelect">
    * {
      -webkit-touch-callout: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
      -ms-touch-action: none;
      touch-action: none;
    }
  </style>
  <title>Touch-Test</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function Init() {
      window.oncontextmenu = function () { return false; };

      document.getElementById('mouseBox').addEventListener('mousedown', mouseBoxDown, false);
      document.getElementById('mouseBox').addEventListener('mouseup', mouseBoxUp, false);
      document.getElementById('mouseBox').addEventListener('mouseleave', mouseBoxUp, false);

      document.getElementById('touchBox').addEventListener('touchstart', touchBoxDown, false);
      document.getElementById('touchBox').addEventListener('touchend', touchBoxUp, false);
      document.getElementById('touchBox').addEventListener('touchcancel', touchBoxUp, false);

      document.getElementById('pointerBox').addEventListener('pointerdown', pointerBoxDown, false);
      document.getElementById('pointerBox').addEventListener('pointerup', pointerBoxUp, false);
      document.getElementById('pointerBox').addEventListener('pointercancel', pointerBoxUp, false);
      document.getElementById('pointerBox').addEventListener('pointerleave', pointerBoxUp, false);
      document.getElementById('pointerBox').addEventListener('pointerout', pointerBoxUp, false);
    }

    function mouseBoxDown(evt) {
      document.getElementById('mouseBox').style.backgroundColor = '#d00000';
    }

    function mouseBoxUp(evt) {
      document.getElementById('mouseBox').style.backgroundColor = '#eee';
    }

    function touchBoxDown(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      document.getElementById('touchBox').style.backgroundColor = '#00d000';
    }

    function touchBoxUp(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      document.getElementById('touchBox').style.backgroundColor = '#eee';
    }

    function pointerBoxDown(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      document.getElementById('pointerBox').style.backgroundColor = '#0000d0';
    }

    function pointerBoxUp(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      document.getElementById('pointerBox').style.backgroundColor = '#eee';
    }

  </script>
</head>
<body onload="Init()">
  <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #eee" id="mouseBox"></div>
  <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; top: 120px; position: absolute; background-color: #eee" id="touchBox"></div>
  <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; top: 240px; position: absolute; background-color: #eee" id="pointerBox"></div>
</body>
</html>
```